# insertion and updation at the same time oracle forms 11g

Tags: insert, oracle11g, sql-update, oracleforms

I have two datablocks A and B.Block A has a foreign key corresponding to Block B.I want insertion and updation to happen in both the blocks.

I have a situation where when the details of the value changed in block B during updation is not present in the DB,then the values has to be inserted in the db and other changes in Block A has to be updated.

So I am moving from Insertion to updation here

In my case , Insertion is happening but my Block A changes are not getting updated .Instead I am getting."Record Already Inserted" error.

Any ideas would be of much help..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the POST built-in. You can call it when navigating to detail block, to make sure the master record is already in the DB. It will trigger any insert or update validation, but the record won't be commited yet.

About the "Record Already Inserted" error, from form builder help:

> FRM-40600:  Record has already been inserted.
>
> Cause: You attempted to insert or update a record, but uniqueness is enforced on the block's primary key items.  The record, as inserted or updated, is not unique.
>
> Action:    Change the values in one or more primary key fields of the current record, making them unique.  If the requirement of unique primary key fields creates difficulties, consider eliminating the constraint.

Comment: post is not helping either

Comment: Have you created a relation between the blocks?
If everything is properly configured, you may end up writing ON-INSERT and ON-UPDATE triggers to do the operations correctly.